# Ansible where set ansible_user and ansible_ssh_pass in role

Tags: ansible

I am creating my first role in ansible to install packages through apt as it is a task I usually do on a daily basis.

```
apt
├── apt_install_package.yaml
├── server.yaml
├── tasks
│   └── main.yaml
└── vars
    └── main.yaml

# file: apt_install_package.yaml

- name: apt role
  hosts: server
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  roles:
  - apt

# tasks
- name: install package
  apt: 
   name: "{{ package }}" 
   state: present
   update_cache:  True
  with_items: "{{ package }}"

#vars
---
package:
  - nginx
  - supervisor

#inventory
---
server:
  hosts:
    new-server:
      ansible_host: 10.54.x.x
```

In order to install the packages I must indicate a user of ssh but I do not know where to indicate it.

My idea is to indicate parameters with variables, something similar to this

```
  ansible_user: "{{ myuser }}"
  ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ mypass }}"
  ansible_become_pass: "{{ mypass }}"
```

Any sugestions??

Regards,

Comment: You normally set these values in your [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_inventory.html), since they often differ per host (or per group of hosts).

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using keypair authentication with ssh rather than passwords, and as an alternative to Ansible's inventory for remote username etc you could also use an ssh config file (see the man page for `ssh_config`) where you can have per-host and default ssh settings.

Comment: Although @larsks link above still contains very interesting and quite accurate information about building an inventory, it was written for ansible v2.3. You might want to read that info on the [latest documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

Answer (score 8):

As per the [latest documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) from Ansible regarding inventory sources, an SSH password can be configured using the `ansible_password` keyword while an SSH user is specified by `ansible_user` keyword, for any given host or host group entry.

It is worth mentioning that in order to implement SSH password login for hosts with Ansible, the [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) program is required on the controller. Any plays will otherwise fail due to an error injecting the password while initializing connections.

Define these keywords within your existing inventory in the following manner:

```
#inventory
---
server:
  hosts:
    new-server:
      ansible_host: 10.54.x.x
      ansible_user: <username>
      ansible_password: <password>
      ansible_become_password: <password>
```

The YAML plugin will parse your host configuration parameters from the inventory source and they will be appended host/group variables used for establishing an SSH connection.

The major disadvantage in this scenario is the fact that your authentication secrets will be stored in plain text, and usually Ansible is IaC committed to source control repositories. Unacceptable in production environments.

Consider using a lookup plugin such as [env](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/env_lookup.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-env-lookup) or [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-file-lookup) to render password secrets dynamically from the controller and prevent leakage.

```
#inventory
---
server:
  hosts:
    new-server:
      ansible_host: 10.54.x.x
      ansible_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'MY_SECRET_ANSIBLE_USER') }}"
      ansible_password: "{{ lookup('file', '/path/to/password') }}"
      ansible_become_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'MY_SECRET_BECOME_PASSWORD') }}"
```

Other lookup plugins may also be of use to you depending on your use-case, and can be further researched [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_lookup.html).

Alternatively, you could designate a default remote connection user, connection user password, and become password separately within your Ansible configuration file, usually located at `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

Read more about available configuration options in Ansible [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASSWORD_FILE).

All three mentioned configuration options can be specified under the `[defaults]` INI section as:

`remote_user`: default connection username

`connection_password_file`: default connection password file

`become_password_file`: default become password file

NOTE: `connection_password_file`  and `become_password_file` must be a filesystem path containing the password with which Ansible should use to login or escalate privileges. Storing a default password as plain-text string within the configuration file is not supported.

Another option involves environment variables being present at the time of playbook execution. Either export or pass them explicitly via the command line at the time of playbook execution.

`ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER`: default connection username

`ANSIBLE_CONNECTION_PASSWORD_FILE`: default connection password file

`ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASSWORD_FILE`: default become password file

Such as the following:

`ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASSWORD_FILE="/path/to/become_password" ansible-playbook ...`

This approach is considerably less efficient unless you update the shell profile of the Ansible run user on the controller to set these variables upon login automatically. Generally not recommended for sensitive data such as passwords.

In regards to security, SSH key-pair authentication is preferred whenever possible. However, the second best approach would be to vault the sensitive passwords using `ansible-vault`.

Vault allows you to encrypt data at rest, and reference it within inventory/plays without risk of compromise.

Review this [link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) to gain understanding of available procedures and get started.